# Call implemented interface methods, but distinguish their calls on certain objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

I'm facing a design issue where I'm trying to call all objects that implement a certain interface IInitialize that has a method "Initialize".

"IInitialize" can implement several classes like GameManager, Player, Enemy etc.

However IInitialize can be also implemented in other classes that don't have to Initialize themselves in that exact moment when I want to let's say restart the game, so I need some sort of "categorization" of Init calls so other classes don't get called when I don't need them to be.

So here I have few options like creating another empty subclass of "IInitialize"  and just make a call to "Initialize" through this type. All classes that Implement subclass will get this call. (it works, but it is a correct approach - not code smell?).

Another option is to create a generic "Initialize" interface and just pass the string or something similar to distinguish between calls.

**So to recap: I implement the interface to various classes, let's say "ILife" which has a method "Die" to implement in the class. However I don't want all objects of type to die at a certain time, just the required ones.**

Any other ideas or am I going in the wrong direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use some event information passed into the `Initialize` methods that let's the classes themselves decide whether to initialize or not on certain event types (new game, restart) or you could create some extra marker interfaces and then lookup classes that implement say `IRestartable`

Comment: If you want to have an interface with two methods but in some classes only one method, you probably need two interfaces, one deriving from another and adding that second method

Comment: I meant one interface like "IInitializable" and other empty interfaces (that inherit from this one), called like "IInitializableMenu", "IInitializableGame", etc. This way it's easy to tell which objects get the "Initialization" call because you implement different interfaces in classes.

Comment: If your question is, "I want to do [thing] but not exactly [thing]" your architecture is wrong. If you have an interface that supplies an `Initialization` method, but you don't want to call ALL of them, you need 2 interfaces: one for the ALL call and one for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged *C#* I will use C# in the code examples. But the solutions apply to any object oriented language as well.

This is a question of  design. You have many options to solve this. I will show three:

**1. Use separate interfaces that serve a certain scenarios**

```
interface IInitializable
{
  void Initialize();
}

interface IGameStartInitializable : IInitialize
{
}
```

If both interfaces share absolutely the same members, this solution or especially the `IGameStartInitializable` inteface would have the character of a tagging interface and a proof of bad design.

I don't recommend this solution.

**2. Use separate containers for the objects**

```
public List<IInitialize> DefaultInitializables = new List<IInitialize>();

public List<IInitialize> GameStartupInitializables = new List<IInitialize>();
```

Now that you added each objects to the corresponding collection you can easily iterate over them. This is more elegant than the first solution.

**3. Use events**

Introducing a `GameStarting` and `GameStarted` events would delegate the initialization to the type itself. Let the corresponding instances of type `IInitialize` subscribe to this event. Their event handler will invoke `IInitialize.Initialize()` on themselves.

```
class Player : IInitialize
{
  public Player(IGameEngine gameEngine)
  {
    gameEngine.Starting += InitializeOnGameStarting;
  }

  private void InitializeOnGameStarting(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    gameEngine.Starting -= InitializeOnGameStarting;

    // Invoke the implemented member of IInitialize
    Initialize();
  }
}
```

This is the most elegant way. It is extensible since every implementation handles it's own initialization. No filtering or sorting (add implementations to the right collection) and iterations necessary.